# If velocity of a particle is $v=v_0(1-e^{-bt})$, where $v_0$ and $b$ are constants, Mark the correct option

Tags: derivatives

Options are

A) the acceleration of the particle is $v_0b$ at $t=0$

B) the maximum velocity is $v_0$

C) the maximum velocity is $ev_0$

D) the minimum velocity is $v_0$

It’s fairly obvious that the option a is correct, so that’s not a problem.

However, when you look at option b, which is also the right answer according to the answer key, things start to get weird.

To find maximum velocity we simply equate its derivative to 0.

$$\frac{dv}{dx} = 0$$ So either $v_0=0$ or $b=0$

Plugging the values in first equation we get

$$v=0$$ OR
$$v=v_0(1-e^0)$$
$$\Rightarrow v=0$$

So the maximum velocity is zero, but the answer key says it’s $v_0$. How do we arrive at the answer?

Comment: A) is not correct.

Comment: We can safely say that $v_0 \neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, so the derivative method doesn't produce the correct answer. What are the other options for finding the maxima of a function, I mean other than finding the derivative?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy A is correct. It has been confirmed.

Comment: @MattiP. I really don’t know

Comment: The acceleration at $t=0$ is $-b v_0$.

Comment: By the way, are there any limits to $t$, for example $t\geq 0$ ?

Comment: I see where you are going wrong. There two negative signs, they just cancel each other out. I suggest you try it again. Also derivative of the inner function is $(-e^{bt})(-bt)$

Comment: @MattiP. None I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If $v=v_0(1-e^{-b~t})=v_0 - v_0~e^{-b~t}$ is the velocity, then $a = dv/dt=v_0~b~e^{-b~t}$ is the acceleration. The acceleration of the particle is $ v_0~b$ at $t=0$. The maximum velocity happens where the velocity function $v(t) = v_0 - v_0~e^{-b~t}$ reaches it's maximum value. If we assume $v_0 > 0$ and $b > 0$, then $v_{\text{max}} = v_0$ at $t=0$. Check for $v_0 < 0$ and $b < 0$ **or** $v_0 > 0$ and $b < 0$ **or** $v_0 < 0$ and $b > 0$ **or** $v_0 > 0$ and $b > 0$ what happens with the function $v(t)$ to find out $v_{\text{min}}$ and $v_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: Sorry, it’s my mistake. The question has been edited, so that there is negative sign in the power. $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is not negative, it is $v_0b$ at t=0.